# Auto deploy mkdocs with versionning using mike on gitlab pages

Tags: gitlab-ci, doc, mkdocs, gitlab-pages

I'm willing to deploy a new version of the doc each time I commit a tag on gitlab.
I'm using mike for the mkdocs versionning.

I want the versionning to be handle directly on the remote repository not locally.

Locally, I perfom my changes but each time I send a new tag, I would like the get a new added version of the doc on my gitlab page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution [here](https://github.com/jimporter/mike/issues/25).

Here is my adaptation:

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"
    PAGES_BRANCH: gl-pages
    HTTPS_REMOTE: https://gitlab-ci-token:${ACCESS_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}.git
  before_script:
    - pip install mkdocs mike
    - git config user.name $GITLAB_USER_NAME
    - git config user.email $GITLAB_USER_EMAIL
    - git fetch origin $PAGES_BRANCH && git checkout -b $PAGES_BRANCH origin/$PAGES_BRANCH || echo "Pages branch not deployed yet."
    - git checkout $CI_COMMIT_SHA
  script:
   - mike deploy --rebase --prefix public -r $HTTPS_REMOTE -p -b $PAGES_BRANCH -u $CI_COMMIT_TAG latest
   - mike set-default --rebase --prefix public -r $HTTPS_REMOTE -p -b $PAGES_BRANCH latest
   - git checkout $PAGES_BRANCH -- public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
     - public/
  only:
    - tags
```